# Python Selenium - fetching titles and links in a loop

Tags: python, selenium

I have trying to do this using Selenium in Python:

title1

link1

title2

link2
...

Currently I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

PATH = r"C:\Users\Desktop\py\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
searchbar = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='gLFyf')
searchbar.send_keys('selenium')
searchbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
titles = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='LC20lb')
links = driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='a')
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

However, the links printed out are Google search links, instead of the links of the websites themselves. Also, all the links are printed out before the titles (I understand why this happens but don't know how to fix that)

May I ask what are the ways to solve the 2 problems? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want the links and titles to be printed together?

Comment: @Zero yes, like title1 (enter) link1 (enter) title2 (enter) link2... but not title1234 then link1234

Comment: There aren't equal numbers or titles and links so for the links without titles it should be blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `for` loop in your code with,

```
for i, link in enumerate(links):
    try:
        print(titles[i].text)
    except:
        pass
    print(link.get_attribute("href"));print()
```

Output -

```
Selenium Tutorial for Beginners: Learn WebDriver & Testing
https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHuNKqiOv3AhXITWwGHZXxBlwQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw

Selenium: Definition, How it works and Why you need it
https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHuNKqiOv3AhXITWwGHZXxBlwQ_AUoAnoECAIQBA

What Is Selenium � A Tutorial on How to Use ... - LambdaTest
https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHuNKqiOv3AhXITWwGHZXxBlwQ_AUoA3oECAIQBQ
```